# Highcharts 2nd yaxis not scaling

Tags: highcharts

i can see 2 y axes but how can i scale the second? Where i have to put code? I get data from database using json.php which i don't include because i am sure i get results...as i said i can see lines........

```
function InitHighChart()
{
$("#chart").html("Wait, Loading graph...");

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        borderColor: '#a1a1a1',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 13,
        alignTicks: false,
        height: 550
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ενεργός Ισχύς / Τάση',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{}],
        labels: {
            step: 15,
            rotation: -75
        }
    },

     yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value} MWatt',


        },
        title: {
            text: 'Ενεργός Ισχύς',

        }

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Τάση',

        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} V',

        },
        opposite: true
    }],


    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                s += '<br/>'+point.series.name+': '+point.y;
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{},{}]
};

$.ajax({
    url: "json.php",
    data: 'show=impression',
    type:'post',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        options.xAxis.categories = data.datetime;
        options.series[0].name = '...';
        options.series[0].data = data.ActiveData;
        options.series[1].name = '...';
        options.series[1].data = data.VoltageData;

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
    },
});

}
```

Comment: By scale, you mean set different [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval) or not [aligning](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) ticks?

Comment: Second link...I mean..yaxis1 to scale according to yaxis1 data and yaxis2 according to yaxis2 data.i get only one yaxis on the left..i can't see the right one..Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you assigned any series to second y axis? That might be the problem.

API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.yAxis

```
series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5]
    }, {
        data: [3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 6, 3, 3, 4, 6],
        yAxis: 1
}]
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boog4dpe/

in your code you should add line in

```
$.ajax({
    url: "json.php",
    data: 'show=impression',
    type:'post',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        options.xAxis.categories = data.datetime;
        options.series[0].name = '...';
        options.series[0].data = data.ActiveData;
        options.series[1].name = '...';
        options.series[1].data = data.VoltageData;

        options.series[1].yAxis = 1; //added line

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
    },
});
```

Comment: options.series[1].data = data.VoltageData; makes this. i get data from querying a database...is there any other way to push data using code format as u wrote? i am new to highcharts...looked some examples and the way i ve done shows the two lines but not the second yaxis..Thank u very much